# Converting Mock concrete object to interface resulting empty implementation

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I've using moq for a while for unit testing,
I was wondering why my mock object <s>cannot be converted to interface even though it implement the interface method it</s> return nothing after it is converted to interface, here is my simple code:

```
POSRepository repo = this.mockPosRepository.Object;
IPOSRepository posRepo = repo;
if(repo.Prices.Count() > 0) // True
if(posRepo.Prices.Count() > 0) // false
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: How do you create `this.mockPosRepository`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `As` method to add interfaces to the mock object, like this:

```
mockPosRepository.As<IPOSRepository>();
```

Unfortunately, moq doesn't just work out that it should be able to convert objects if the class implements the interface.

Answer (score 0):

@domysee, thx for your response I've managed to solved the issue by checking the creation process, i should create a real class instead a mock class...i create a problem similar like this code

```
   [TestMethod]
    public void Test_Clean_Price()
    {
        Mock<CalcProcessor> calcProcessor = new Mock<CalcProcessor>();
        calcProcessor.Setup(s => s.AddProcessor(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(1);
        Mock<Calc> calc = new Mock<Calc>(calcProcessor.Object);//this should not a mock object
        ICalc icalc = calc.Object;
        int resultObject = calc.Object.Add(1, 2);
        int resultInterface = icalc.Add(1, 2);

        Assert.AreEqual(1,resultObject);//result 0
        Assert.AreEqual(1, resultInterface);//result 0

    }
}
public class CalcProcessor
{
    public virtual int AddProcessor(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}

public class Calc : ICalc
{
    private CalcProcessor cp;

    public Calc(CalcProcessor calcp)
    {
        this.cp = calcp;
    }
    public virtual int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return this.cp.AddProcessor(a,b);
    }

    public virtual int Substract(int a, int b)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}


public interface ICalc
{
    int Add(int a, int b);

    int Substract(int a, int b);
}
```